# Learning electronics on Tinkercad, need help with understanding how a comparator works

Tags: comparator

I have set up a circuit as in the picture:

[image]

[image]

I do not understand why output 2 of the comparator is 0V, when the input2 + is clearly higer voltage than input2 -. Shouldn't output2 give a high voltage?

[Here is a share link to the setup.](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/j2jaPRwxPOu-spectacular-elzing/editel?sharecode=k15sUMhVQxwQXSUnJELt2wdhJ-00O21gd7YF8gx2kK8)

Answer (score 1):

I see two errors already. There are probably more.

1. You have a 1kΩ resistor between battery positive and the rest of the circuit. That's not how you should power this circuit, and doesn't agree with your schematic.
2. Follow the comparator IC's power supply pins. You find that they both are connected to battery negative. This is not how you should power that IC, and also doesn't agree with the schematic.

Please try to draw schematics which are easier to read. It will help you troubleshoot your own circuit, and help others see what you are trying to achieve. This is how I would draw it (I *think*, because yours is so hard to read, I may have got something different):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN4pLP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The first thing to do is remove R9, its effect on the circuit is severely detrimental.

Your arrangement of R10, R11 and RPOT2 doesn't make any sense to me, I'm not sure what you expect. I'm pretty sure this is not what you intended. I certainly won't check your TinkerCad to see if it conforms, when that's definitely something you can do for yourself, even as a beginner.

The other thing I would point out is that the LED will never light, because the output of an LM393 comparator is [open-collector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector), meaning that it cannot "pull" its output to \$V_{CC}\$ potential, only to \$GND\$ potential. If you intend for the comparator to illuminate the LED, then you must connect it like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTm4Ci.png)</sup>

Comment: Hi, thank your for your answer, i have edited the schematic, and added a share link for easier understanding, about your first point, is it not always a good idea to have a limiting resistor to avoid damaging errors?

Comment: @CorentinSalomon No, it's almost never a good idea. It might be good under certain circumstances to protect one element somewhere, but not the whole circuit like this. You will of course make mistakes, and you will damage things, that's a given, we all did. However you can't just throw in a resistor to protect your circuit from mistakes unless you understand what the consequences will be for behaviour. Instead of protecting the whole circuit from your mistakes, fix mistakes before connecting the battery.

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely difficult to follow your schematic.

With all the other problems solved, your question was how a comparator works.

That specific comparator, like many others, has an open-drain output.

So that comparator can not output current and light up your LED if connected like that.

You might think the equivalent of the comparator output is a switch or pushbutton, that either closes the circuit and connects the output to ground, or leaves the circuit open so no current flows.